# Bing map silverlight control content rendering issue when page gets refresh

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, bing-maps

When Bing map control loads for first time on any browser all pushpin on map are visible.
Bing map control renders perfectly.

Then I refresh browser it create rendering issue some custom pushpin on map gets disappeared. This behavior continues with pushpin. Pushpin are (.png) images and I am not using default bing map thumbtacks.

May be it is issue of browser caching content or Bing map control rendering issues on various browsers.

Please respond soon.

Answer (score 0):

Convert .png to xaml then pushpin disapper issues will be solved
Making pushpin silverlight native(.xaml) will solve the problem
Its a browser cache issues that makes .png pin disapper